# What happens when comparing strings with >,< operators? Python

Tags: python, string

I am trying to understand what happens when you compare strings with the >,< operators in Python. I know for sure that it doesn't compare the length of the string. Does it compare the sum of their ASCII values?

```
>>>a='aa'
>>>b='bb'
>>>b>a
True
```

Answer (score 1):

From [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in):

> Strings are compared [lexicographically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) using the numeric equivalents
>   (the result of the built-in function `ord()`) of their characters.
>   Unicode and 8-bit strings are fully interoperable in this behavior[[4](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#id23)].

Answer (score 1):

The operators are based on the lexicographic order of the strings characters.  In your case `b[0] > a[0]`, therefore the statement returns true.  If `a[0]` was equal to `b[0]` the next character would be compared and so forth.

Comment: I see. So its their ASCII value compared until it reaches a true value?